# Mapping Collections with Automapper?

Tags: vb.net, collections, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper, entity-framework-6.1

I done a lot of searching but am not sure how map collections with Automapper.

Given:

```
Public Class PostSummaryDTO
        Public Property PostId As Integer
        Public Property PostGuid As Guid
        Public Property PostTitle As String
        Public Property PostSummary As String
        Public Property PostDateCreated As DateTime
        Public Property PostIsPublished As Boolean
        Public Property PostText As String
        Public Property PostCategory As ICollection(Of be_Categories)
        Public Property PostTag As ICollection(Of be_PostTag)
        Public Author As String
    End Class
```

and

```
Public Class be_PostsViewModel
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Property Author As String
        <DisplayName("Title")> <Required(ErrorMessage:="Your post must have a title")>
            Public Property PostTitle As String
        <DisplayName("My Snarky Text")> Public Property PostSummary As String
        <DisplayName("Post")> Public Property PostText As String
        <UIHint("DateCreated")> <DisplayName("Date Created")> Property PostDateCreated    
            As DateTime?
        <DisplayName("Publish")> Public Property PostIsPublished As Boolean
        Public Property PostGuid As Guid
        Public Property BlogId As Guid
        <DataType(DataType.MultilineText)> <UIHint("Tags")> <DisplayName("Tags")>
           Public Property PostTags As ICollection(Of be_PostTag)
        <DisplayName("Category")> <UIHint("Categories")> Public Property
            PostCategory As ICollection(Of CategoriesViewModel)

    End Class
```

How do I map `Public Property PostCategory As ICollection(Of be_Categories)` to `Public Property PostCategory As ICollection(Of CategoriesViewModel)`

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687240/c-sharp-automapper-map-collection-of-objects, it should be straightforward, by just Map<PostCategory, CategoriesViewModel>, and this will be enough when you have a collection or list.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the mapping for `be_Categories` to `CategoriesViewModel` and `PostSummaryDTO` to `be_PostsViewModel` AutoMapper will automatically understand that and take care of the rest.

```
' Do this only once in your application
Mapper.CreateMap(Of be_Categories, CategoriesViewModel)()
Mapper.CreateMap(Of PostSummaryDTO, be_PostsViewModel)()

Dim yourDTO = New PostSummaryDTO()
' Set all your DTO values here

' Call AutoMapper
Dim vm As be_PostsViewModel = Mapper.Map(Of be_PostsViewModel)(yourDTO)
```

`vm` now should have all your properties nicely mapped, including your `Collection`. It can automatically map collections when their "inside types" are mapped. You can see all the supported collections [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays).

I just tested this and it works.

**Update:** If you just want to map collections straight from one variable to another, you would have to do this:

```
' Create a mapping for the types inside the collection
Mapper.CreateMap(Of be_Categories, CategoriesViewModel)()

' Declare a collection of be_Categories
Dim col As New List(Of be_Categories)()
' Insert all the items
Dim cat = New be_Categories()
col.Add(cat)

' Call AutoMapper stating that you want a List as return
Dim vm As List(Of CategoriesViewModel) = Mapper.Map(Of List(Of CategoriesViewModel))(col)
```

Again, it will automatically create a `List(Of CategoriesViewModel)` for you because you created the mapping for the inner types.

Kind of unrelated, but please note that AutoMapper won't understand that `Id` and `PostId` refer to the same property.
You can learn about all AutoMapper's conventions [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'attributions'? Sorry for the dumb question but am new to Automapper and could you give an example? thanks

Comment: I mean you set all the values in your source object. Like `dto.PostTitle = "Title"`, `dto.PostText = "Text"`. The code I used on my answer is a complete working example. Did you try it?